# Hive collect list is not working with millions of records

Tags: hive, collect

I have a hive query in outer query I am using collect_list. The inner query I have a ordered list of 1.8 million records. When I run the query every time 500-600 records giving wrong result and missing the order in a pattern. I used brickhouse jar also with collect udf. This is also giving same result with 500-600 records differed. I don't have any clue how to debug.

```
select concat_ws('','',collect_list(host)),
  concat_ws('','',collect_list(cast(total_data_volume_host as string))),
  concat_ws('','',collect_list(cast(event_duration_host as string))),
  concat_ws('','',collect_list(application_name)),
  concat_ws('','',collect_list(cast(total_data_volume_app as string))),
  concat_ws('','',collect_list(cast(event_duration_app as string))),
```

Comment: Voted to close. I'm sorry, but you are failing to present a clear picture of the source data, the requested result and the transformation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using ORDER BY is a sub-query does not guarantee an ordered array.
We are going to use **sort_array** for that.
**concat_ws** works only with array of strings so you are casting your values to string **before** using **collect_list**.
The problem now is that the natural order of the elements is changed -
100 > 20 but '20' > '100' (alphabetic order).
The work around is to **lpad** the values with spaces, sort, concat and then remove the spaces.

```
with t as (select explode(array(100,20,3)) as i) 
select translate(concat_ws(',',sort_array(collect_list(lpad(cast(i as string),10,' ')))),' ','') 
from t;
```

> 3,20,100

Comment: we dont want to chage order of inner query

Comment: I don't understand the comment. In any case, "order of inner query" is not something you can build on.

Comment: for each user we are calculating volume consume for top 20 sites. and we need all in single line ,with out collect_list we are getting the data in correct order but when we are using collect_list some records getting deffered that is 500 out of 1.6 million.so we need some alternative which will do same function as collect_list

Comment: What do you mean by "deffered"? I thought the issue was the order of elements within the collect_list. Can you had a small data example to your post?

Comment: due to limitations i added in another answer please check and suggest